# Selenium IDE - execute a function foo.bar.getmyinfo()

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm new to selenium IDE, but from the chrome devtools console, i can run a function like foo.bar.getmyinfo() . Can you execute this function and store the returned info in Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. See [execute-script](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#execute-script).

```
execute-script | return foo.bar.getmyinfo(); | result
```

Comment: Sorry for delay but missed your reply - I had tried this but keep getting an undefined message - e.g. foo is not defined.

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Comment: Is *foo.bar.getmyinfo()* function of chrome's extention? after executing *foo.bar.getmyinfo()* in the devtools console I get error 'foo is not defined'.